# Animation supposed to change according to a variable in another java file

Tags: java, animation, jpanel

So basically I have my main code (TuringSimLS.java) and my  animation code (Animation.java)
Animation.java creates a number of boxes (dependent on the length of an array in my TuringSimLS.java. The length of this array does not change). Now there is a variable in my TuringSimLS.java which has a variable pointer (this one changes). This pointer decides which box in my animation is in the middle. For example if there are 7 boxes, and the pointer is 6, the box in the middle will have one box to it's right and five to it's left (making it the 6th of boxes). When the pointer changes all the boxes move until the required box is in the middle. The problem is that my method (which changes the value of pointer) finishes running and then my    animation starts. So no animation ends up happening (as the pointer's value returns to the value it initially was in the beginning). I need my animation to happen as soon as the variable pointer's value changes.

Part of my main code (TuringSimLS.java)

```
public static int[] POINTER = new int[1]; // My global variable. How i tell my Animation.java
                                          // What the current value of pointer is

 static String[] processTape(String[][] Quints, String[] Tape, int TapeInitial) {
       int pointer = TapeInitial;
       POINTER[0] = pointer;
       ...
       ...
       Animation.main(Quints, Tape, TapeInitial); // <- animation started here
       while (!currentDir.equals("H")) { // <- IMPORTANT WHILE LOOP as mentioned below
        for (String[] Quint : Quints) {
            if (Quint[0].equals(currentState) && Quint[1].equals(Tape[pointer])) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TuringSimLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                Tape[pointer] = Quint[3];
                ...
                ...
                if (currentDir.equals("R")) {pointer += 1;}   // pointer changes here
                if (currentDir.equals("L")) {pointer -= 1;}
                symbolFound = true;
                startFound = true;
                POINTER[0] = pointer; 
                //Here is where i want the animation to start as in 
                //moving of the already drawn boxes
                //System.out.println(POINTER[0]);
                break;
            }
        }

         }
   return Tape;
}
```

Here is my Animition.java:

```
package turingsimls;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;    // Imports ActionEvent, ActionListener
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{  
   Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
   int x = 0;
   int xtri = 300;
   int ytri = 30;
   public static int[] C = new int[1];
   public static int[] Number = new int[1];
   public static int[] POINTER2 = new int[1];

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);   //9
       g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
       for (int i = 0; i < Number[0]; i++)
              g.fillRect((280 + (40 + 20)*i) + C[0], 50, 40, 30);
       int xpoly[] = {xtri , xtri + 10, xtri - 10 };
       int ypoly[] = {ytri, ytri - 10, ytri - 10};
       g.drawPolygon(xpoly, ypoly, xpoly.length);

       tm.start();
   }

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
          //Here C changes according to the pointer
          //Which in turn changes the XPos of the rectangles
         if (!(C[0] == -60 * TuringSimLS.POINTER[0])){
           if ((C[0] < -60 * TuringSimLS.POINTER[0]))  
               C[0] += 10;

           if ((C[0] > -60 * TuringSimLS.POINTER[0]))
               C[0] -= 10;
       }
       System.out.println(C[0]);
       System.out.println(TuringSimLS.POINTER[0]);
       repaint();

   }

   public static void main(String[][] Quints, String[] Tape, int TapeInitial) {
       Animation t = new Animation();  //2
       JFrame jf = new JFrame();
       jf.setTitle("Animation");
       jf.setSize(600, 400);
       jf.setVisible(true);
       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       jf.add(t);
       Number[0] = Tape.length - 1;
       C[0] = -60 * TapeInitial;
   }
}
```

processTape() starts the animation and produces the first rectangles correctly. The problem is the entire "Important while loop" runs before actionPerformed() runs for the second time. So the animation doesnt process the changes of pointer.

Comment: You should let the animation control the turing logic. Meaning that the animating class calls something like perform step on your `TuringSlimLs` instead of trying to synchronize two threads.

Comment: The problem is that processTape is a static method, while actionPerformed is non-static. How can i get actionPerformed to call a static method? Sorry but I'm a bit new to java and gui

Comment: You can call static methods without the need for an instance, to invoke the method you just write `Classname.methodname()`.